# How is this website's architecture structured?

Tags: javascript, jquery, architecture

refer to this URL: `http://imagemechanics.com.au/`

Every page seems to have its own unique URL, but the "/#!/" leads me to believe it's all one giant page with anchor tags defining the sections. Is each section truly its own .html page or is it just one page?

Comment: Just a curiosity... the site in question doesn't appear to have constructed the URLs of its `/blog/` section correctly - none of it is indexed in Google. Requesting the corresponding `?_escaped_fragment_=/blog/...` URL (required by Google) results in a 500 internal server error. However, the sites (few) main pages are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a single page. (This should be obvious just from viewing source.)
There are separate documents, [like this one](http://imagemechanics.com.au/pages/break-it-down?v3), being loaded via Ajax.

In Firefox, open Firebug and enable the Net tab. When you click the navigation links, you'll be able to see the GET requests for them.

Comment: How would one determine what percentage of internet users this animated interface would not be compatible with?

Comment: A similar percentage to those that use Ajax enabled browsers I would have thought. The important metric, however, is how many of _your sites users_ it would be compatible with. I would expect that the site in question has a very high compatibility rate with its expected customers.